# How to add rowspan attribute to dynamically created table cells

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a fairly complex table where one row Looks like this:

```
    |   |     |Thing|thing2|    |    |
    |NR |text |-----|------|text|text|
    |   |     |Thing|thing2|    |    |
```

So i got it so far as to being able to dynamically add the rows, but they are displayed below each other.
Not in the same row with rowspan.
This is the html table body:

```
    <tbody class="b1" id="b1">
<tr>
    <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td rowspan="2">Nr</td>
    <td rowspan="2">C/S</td>
    <td rowspan="2">REG</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Typ</td>
    <td rowspan="2">E<br/>R<br/>K</td>
    <td>PIC</td>
    <td>BTM</td>
    <td>AG's</td>
    <td rowspan="2">DEP</td>
    <td>ETD</td>
    <td>ETA</td>
    <td rowspan="2">DEST</td>
    <td>ETD</td>
    <td>ETA</td>
    <td rowspan="2">DEST</td>
    <td>ETD</td>
    <td>ETA</td>
    <td rowspan="2">DEST</td>
    <td>ETD</td>
    <td>ETA</td>
    <td rowspan="2">DEST</td>
    <td>ETE</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Auftrag</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Ausfall<br/>durch</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Bermerkung</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>BTL</td>
    <td>ACM</td>
    <td>ATD</td>
    <td>ATA</td>
    <td>ATD</td>
    <td>ATA</td>
    <td>ATD</td>
    <td>ATA</td>
    <td>ATD</td>
    <td>ATA</td>
    <td>ATE</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And this is my script for adding new rows:

```
    function addRow(tableID) {
//add row 1
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[2].cells.length;

for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[2].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
        case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
        case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
        case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
    }
}

//add row 2
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[3].cells.length;

for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[3].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
        case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
        case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
        case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
    }
}}
```

so as I said this does add the two rows at once, it just puts them below each other because the rowspan attribtute that Formats the original row is not behing inherited by the new ones.

So this happends:

```
    |Nr   |text  |thing|thing2|text|text|
    |Thing|thing2|
```

Comment: I found the problem but no solution: the problem is that the new rows dont inherit the rowspan="2" Attribute from the old rows, so thats why they dont format in the same way. Is there a way to add that after the rows have been established?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt follow your logic while inserting rows, but i just wanted to show you a way how you can push rows with rowspan. I hope it helps.

```js
function insertRow(tableId){
  // Get a reference to the table
  let tableRef = document.getElementById(tableId);

  // I did not follow your logic, but i suppose you want to add a row similar to previous ones. So..

  let firstRowLenght = tableRef.rows[0].cells.length;
  let secondRowLenght = tableRef.rows[1].cells.length;

  // Insert a row at the end of the table
  let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);

  // for inserting 1. row
  for (i = 0; i < firstRowLenght; i++) {
    // Get previous cell
    let prevCell = tableRef.rows[0].cells.item(i);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index i
    let newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);

    // Append a text node to the cell
    let newText = document.createTextNode(prevCell.innerText + "(inserted)");
    newCell.rowSpan = prevCell.rowSpan;
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
  }

  // Insert a row at the end of the table second time
  let newRow2 = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
  
  // for inserting 2. row
  for (i = 0; i < secondRowLenght; i++) {
    // Get previous cell
    let prevCell = tableRef.rows[1].cells.item(i);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index i
    let newCell = newRow2.insertCell(i);

    // Append a text node to the cell
    let newText = document.createTextNode(prevCell.innerText + "(inserted)");
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
  }
}

insertRow("table-id");
```

```css
.table {
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #979797   ;   
}

.table td {
    border: 1px solid #979797   ;   ;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <table class="table" id="table-id">

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">NR</td>
    <td rowspan="2">text</td> 
    <td>Thing</td>
    <td>Thing2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">text</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Thing</td>
    <td>Thing2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Okay Thank you that works great. I changed the Code from TextNode to innerHTML though to get inserted Elements.
And i wanted to ask: does newCell.rowSpan = prevCell.rowSpan work the same with other Attributes like classes or names?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand this code from the first time so,
I rewrited the code to make it more clear for newbie:

```
function insertTable(tableId){
// Get a reference to the table
    let tableRef = document.getElementById(tableId);

    let firstRowLenght = 5;
    let secondRowLenght = 4;

    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.border = "1";

// Insert a row at the end of the table
    let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);

// for inserting 1. row
    for (i = 0; i < firstRowLenght; i++) {
    // Get previous cell
        let prevCell = table.rows[0].cells.item(i);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index i
        let newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
        newCell.innerHTML = "inserted Cell";

        if(i === 3) { newCell.rowSpan = "2";}
    }

// Insert a row at the end of the table second time
    let newRow2 = table.insertRow(-1);

// for inserting 2. row
    for (i = 0; i < secondRowLenght; i++) {
    // Get previous cell
        let prevCell = table.rows[1].cells.item(i);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index i
        let newCell = newRow2.insertCell(i);
        newCell.innerHTML = "inserted Cell";
    }
    tableRef.appendChild(table);
}
```